# Interop with MS Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-formula

I am trying to write a set of data to excel file using VB.NET. While using the function `Autofit()` following error is returned at run time:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '0x800A03EC'

The exact line of code which I have written is given below.

```
shXL.Range("A", "I").Rows.AutoFit()
```

where `shXL` is the worksheet definition.

All other functions on `shXL` are executing properly.

Comment: Why do you use Rows to autofit when you have selected columns?

Comment: thats a typo error. I have tried .columns and still encountering the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I too don't understand why you're specifying columns for autofitting the rows but try this ...

```
shXL.Range("A:I").Rows.AutoFit()
```